# Excel - Aggregate Function to Average Reciprocals

Tags: excel, aggregate

I'm trying to use the aggregate function to take the average of the reciprocals of an array of values. This works fine for averaging the given values but doesn't seem to be working on their reciprocals. Below is the function I'm using:

Works fine: `=AGGREGATE(1, 6, AA11:AA16)`

Not working: `=AGGREGATE(1, 6, 1/(AA11:AA16))`

Does anyone know the source of the error and whether or not there's a work-around?

**Clarification**

I cannot use array formulas because they contribute too much to the file size.

Comment: Your first formula has a missing right parentheses.. is that the one that works? It should actually be the one that errors out

Answer (score 0):

You could instead find the average of the reciprocals using an array formula, for example:

```
={AVERAGE(1 / AA11:AA16)}
```

(CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER to enter the array formula)

To ignore error values to fully replicate the aggregate function you have used you could add an `IF` into the array formula:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISERROR(AA11:AA16), "", 1 / AA11:AA16))
```

Alternative option...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/AA11:AA16)/COUNT(AA11:AA16)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I'm actually needing to avoid array formulas because they slow things down so much with the file size I'm working with.

Comment: oh I see, how about formula like this > `=SUMPRODUCT(1/AA11:AA16)/COUNT(AA11:AA16)`?

Comment: though as a note: They are both "array functions" one is inherent the other is forced.  As well Aggregate by nature is an array formula.

Comment: Do you mean that they take arrays as inputs? Isn't there a distinction between a function that takes an array as an input and an 'array formula' that can only be calculated by using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER? The time to calculate seems to be greater for the latter than the former so I think it's worth distinguishing between the two.

Comment: Sam, the sumproduct()/count() formula doesn't seem to work if there are any zeroes or blanks in the range.

Comment: @tjnel I mean an Array formula is any that takes a range and cycles through that range to get an answer, which is what the sumproduct is doing.  It does it inherently, others the array part needs to be forced with ctrl-shift-enter. Sumproduct(1/AA11:AA16) does the same as Sum(1/AA11:AA16) with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Now the inherent array formulas will be a little quicker.

Comment: The reason I was trying to use the Aggregate function is because it's supposed to ignore errors. If there are any blanks or zeroes in the range AA11:AA16 then the reciprocals will give DIV/0 errors. As far as I can tell this causes both of Sam's non-array formula solution to break. Is there a reason Aggregate won't work for this task, since it seems like it's designed to avoid the problems that arise with the proposed work arounds?